# AngularJS - Sorting Test not working but code does

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I realize this must be something silly, but I am having trouble with the unit testing in AngularJS and my script. The code works properly (except the initialization and the test).  The end to end test works though.

Karma Test Error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) Controllers EventsCtrl Should set the default sort to be Start Date FAILED
    Expected undefined to be 'StartDate'.

PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.004 secs / 0.009 secs)
describe('Controllers', function() 
{
    describe('EventsCtrl', function()
    {
        var scope;
        var Control;

        // Before Each Test - Load Module
        beforeEach(module('App'));

        // Before Each Test - Inject Controllers
        beforeEach(inject(function($controller)
        {
            scope = {};
            Control = $controller('EventsCtrl', {$scope:scope});
        }));

        it('Should create "Events" with 2 entries', function()
        {
            expect(Control).toBeDefined();
            expect(Control).not.toBeNull();
            expect(scope.Events.length).toBe(2);
        });

        it('Should set the default sort to be Start Date', function() 
        {
            expect(scope.EventSort).toBe('StartDate');
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope)
{
    $scope.Events = [
    {
        'StartDate': 20140329,
        'StartTime': 100000,
        'Name': 'Event 1',
        'Venue': 'XYZ Venue',
    },
    {
        'StartDate': 20140208,
        'StartTime': 093000,
        'Name': 'Final Event',
        'Venue': 'ABC Venue',
    }
    ];
    $scope.EventSort = 'StartDate';
});
```

HTML snippet

```
Sort by:
    <select ng-model="EventSort">
        <option value="StartDate">Earliest Date</option>
        <option value="Venue">Venue</option>
    </select>

<ul class="EventsList">
    <li ng-repeat="EventData in Events | filter:EventsFilter | orderBy:EventSort">
        {{EventData.Name}}
        <p>{{EventData.StartDate}}</p>
        <p>{{EventData.Venue}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am looking to get the test to work.

On a more advanced note, my second question would be to see if there is a way to tell it to sort on any of the available fields without having to spell them out?  Some sort of list of elements.  Maybe a ng-repeat for the options in the select?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @tasseKATT Sorry, I updated the question with the error text.  The default Start Date is not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that can solve your problem, because you did not tell wich of the two tests is not passing and what the error message is. But on a first glimpse, try to replace:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller)
    {
        scope = {};
        Control = $controller('EventsCtrl', { $scope: scope });
    }));
```

with:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope)
    {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        Control = $controller('EventsCtrl', {$scope:scope});
    }));
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the error originally, but have updated the question with the error.  The $rootScope did not help, nor correct the error.  I have not seen the $rootScope in the tutorial yet, so maybe the rest of the code is not structured enough for this. I am only around the 5 and 6 tutorial step, making changes on my own as the tutorial works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. It turns out to be a stupid error.  I have moved the application file into a Modules subdirectory for the Events, to logically group everything with subdirectories for the large project.

The code I had in the editor and was changing though, was still in the old app/js directory, not the one that the test files or web page were using.

Should move files not copy them until they work.  Thanks again for the suggestions.